# JBOSS - Previos execution of timer is still progress,timer state is IN_TIMEOUT

Tags: java, spring, ejb-3.1, jboss6.x, java-ee-7

I am using JBOSS EAP 6.4 . I have schedule some schedulers in my ScedulerBean using EJB @Shedule annotation as follows. Here the ShedulerBean is dependson StartupBean.

```
@Singleton
@DependsOn("StartupBean")
public class SchedulerBean {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchedulerBean.class);
    private SchedulerInterface schedulerInterface;
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        // some initialization
    }
    @Schedule(second = "1/1", minute = "*", hour = "*",persistent = false)
    public void runSchedulers() {
        logger.info("EJB scheduler pulse start at : " + new Date());
        try {
            schedulerInterface.pulseEverySecond();
            logger.info("EJB scheduler pulse end at : " + new Date());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error in EJB scheduling : ", e);
        }
    }

}
```

But, I am repeatedly getting following warning during JBOSS Deployment. Can any one tell me a way to resolve this?

> A previous execution of timer [ShedularBean] is still in progress,
>   skipping this overlapping scheduled execution at: [Timestamp] as timer
>   state is IN_TIMEOUT

Comment: How did you get rid of this message?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running the task every second, it means that the previous scheduled task (of the current second-1 ) is still in progress when the current task is scheduled.

Hence jboss is informing you that it will skip this execution.

Refer this for more details:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3119

Comment: Thanks. what can we do get rid of that message? is it go away , if we increase the time period?